# Translate SHA512 Hash function from Classic Asp to php/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, asp-classic, base64, sha512

I need to check asp-generated passwords in php/Laravel.
Could you help me to translate this asp code used to generate those passwords?

```vb
password = "xxx"
salt = "yyy"
    
saltedPassword = salt & password
    
Set objUnicode = CreateObject("System.Text.UnicodeEncoding")
arrByte = objUnicode.GetBytes_4(saltedPassword)
    
Set objSHA512 = Server.CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed") 
strHash = objSHA512.ComputeHash_2((arrByte))
    
'Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118947/converting-binary-file-to-base64-string
Dim xml: Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
xml.LoadXml "<root />"
xml.documentElement.dataType = "bin.base64"
xml.documentElement.nodeTypedValue = strHash
ToBase64String = Replace(xml.documentElement.Text,VbLf, "") 

Response.Write "<p>" & ToBase64String & "</p>"
```

I tried with this:

```php
$password = 'xxx';
$salt = 'yyy';
$saltedpass = $salt.$password;
dd( base64_encode( hash('sha512', $saltedpass, true) ) );
```

but I get different strings.

Comment: Hmm... `ToBase64String = Replace(xml.documentElement.Text,VbLf, "")` is probably the difference. The line-feed character is being replaced after the base64 string is generated for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for reply, what would you suggest to do? Adding a similar replace after hash function and before base64_encode function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my go to ASP hashing function for anyone looking to do fast and simple hashing in Classic ASP. It allows you to hash as MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA384 and SHA512, as well as encode as Hex or Base64.

**UPDATE**
I've also included an option to specify a character set too (Unicode or UTF8).

```vb
Function Hash(ByVal Input, HashAlgorithm, CharSet, Encoding)
    
    ' Select the System.Security.Cryptography value.
    
    Select Case uCase(HashAlgorithm)
    
        Case "MD5"
        
            HashAlgorithm = "MD5CryptoServiceProvider"
            
        Case "SHA1"
        
            HashAlgorithm = "SHA1CryptoServiceProvider"
            
        Case "SHA2","SHA256"
        
            HashAlgorithm = "SHA256Managed"
            
        Case "SHA384"
        
            HashAlgorithm = "SHA384Managed"
            
        Case "SHA5","SHA512"
        
            HashAlgorithm = "SHA512Managed"
            
        Case Else
        
            HashAlgorithm = "SHA1CryptoServiceProvider"
    
    End Select
    
    ' Convert the input to bytes if not already.
                
    If NOT VarType(Input) = 8209 Then
                    
        Dim CS : Set CS = Server.CreateObject("System.Text." & CharSet & "Encoding")
        
            Input = CS.GetBytes_4(Input)
                                            
        Set CS = Nothing
        
    End If
    
    ' Perform the hash.
                
    Dim hAlg : Set hAlg = Server.CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography." & HashAlgorithm)
    Dim hEnc : Set hEnc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument").CreateElement("encode")
        
        Encoding = lCase(Encoding)
        
        If Encoding = "base64" OR Encoding = "b64" Then
        
            hEnc.dataType = "bin.base64"
        
        Else
        
            hEnc.dataType = "bin.hex"
        
        End If
        
        hEnc.nodeTypedValue = hAlg.ComputeHash_2((Input))
        Hash = hEnc.Text
        
        Hash = Replace(Hash,VBlf,"")
            
    Set hEnc = Nothing
    Set hAlg = Nothing
    
End Function

Dim password, salt, saltedPassword

password = "xxx"
salt = "yyy"

saltedPassword = salt & password

Response.Write(Hash(saltedPassword,"SHA512","Unicode","Base64"))
```

In this example, I've set it to match your code, so it's using `System.Text.UnicodeEncoding` to get the bytes (although UTF8 should be used by default, it's why your PHP code was returning a different Base64 string), and `Hash = Replace(Hash,VBlf,"")` is needed as `bin.base64` almost always includes a line feed, but PHP never does. This is the Base64 output:

> RLW8OiWU7AN3zhc3Avo7u7OOMjUybf8p8R98dafTPJJPCwfKbxd7soEEZlpXU4CmJ2a4HpGhnLPQFf7at1+yxA==

...which matches the Base64 output generated by your ASP code.

---

Now to achieve the same in PHP, simply use `mb_convert_encoding` with `UTF-16LE` when joining the salt and password:

```php
$password = 'xxx';
$salt = 'yyy';
$saltedpass = mb_convert_encoding($salt.$password,'UTF-16LE');

echo(base64_encode(hash('sha512',$saltedpass,true)));
```

The PHP `hash` function will behave the same as using `System.Text.UnicodeEncoding` in Classic ASP. I don't have Laravel installed, so I could only test using `echo`, `print` or `var_dump`, but not `dd`, here's the Base64 output in PHP:

> RLW8OiWU7AN3zhc3Avo7u7OOMjUybf8p8R98dafTPJJPCwfKbxd7soEEZlpXU4CmJ2a4HpGhnLPQFf7at1+yxA==

They're an exact match.

Comment: Thanks for reply, my problem is that I still have those passwords generated by that asp code. So I need my php code to get the same result.

Comment: @Andrea, I believe I've solved the issue. See the updated answer / code.

Comment: Nice bit of code @Adam +1