# Is it possible to upload a image using the src parameter in PHP?

Tags: php, vbscript, file-upload

I know this question may be wrong one.Anyway I want to know is it possible or not?
I am using the VBscript as client side language and PHP as server side language.By using the VBscript I got a image from the scanner and that image is stored in local system.I want to move it to server without client choosing the file.
`When the scan is completed I display the image in the Image  tag using the VB script`.The image displayed in form.If the user submit the form I want to store the image in server.So `is it possible to upload a image using any method without client need to choose browse button`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Client must somehow select the image to upload, yes?

Comment: @Tom No I dont want to show the browse button to client.It's like a automatic upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible.
Due to obvious security reasons.

Comment: This - if the security reasons aren't obvious: if you were allowed to do this, sites could just grab any file from your filesystem and post it to their servers. User interaction is required.

Comment: If he's already scanning an image from the computer and displaying it on a webpage using VBScript, he could use VBScript to POST to a URL. Thus bypassing the standard form submission all together.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need to create a HTTP POST request with the image encoded as a base 64 string (which is sort of what happens when you post a form with an image upload). An AJAX request would be best I'm not sure whether you can do this with VBScript or not.

This question might help you:
[Base64 Encode String in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496751/base64-encode-string-in-vbscript)

And this article
http://www.bigresource.com/PHP-decoding-base64-into-an-image-EQvGWPIX.html

Comment: But there is no answer for how to get the image in PHP.If you know the way please suggest me.

Comment: @vinothkumar As the answer states, use an AJAX request. If you don't know what that is, google it.