# Jquery Load Image Base on Database

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hello I have a SQL database server that the user can save images as image below:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpHaK.jpg

I already have the string but do not know how to display this form:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,0xFFD8FFE000104A4....." alt="" />
```

is possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a HEX string. Browsers require that data URI to be Base64 encoded.

Have a look here [Convert hex string (image) to base64 (for browser rendering) in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505466/convert-hex-string-image-to-base64-for-browser-rendering-in-vbscript)

In a similar fashion you need to convert the hex to base64 encoded data-uri. This should work on the browser without any problem

Comment: thanks - work for me look here http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en