# Convert a hex string to base64 in an Excel function

Tags: excel, vba, base64, hex

I have a lengthy string of hex values to convert to base64.

I'm looking for a simple format cell function such as `=Hex2b64(Hexstring)` that will accept any length of hex characters.

I have been using http://home.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/ to do my conversion manually. The conversion works and the data is received by all relevant databases and parsed appropriately.

The data I am receiving is hex represented binary, which has been converted in multiple blocks and concatenated into long hex strings in accordance with project documentation that I am not privy to.

A typical Input String would be:

```
Hex= 00014088F6650101393939393939392D30304646463238313030000343332353430342D35353FA10000002805900100002805
```

and the corresponding output would be:

```
B64 = AAFAiPZlAQE5OTk5OTk5LTAwRkZGMjgxMDAAA0MzI1NDA0LTU1P6EAAAAoBZABAAAoAF
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please see this site FAQ on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why would you convert a hex string to base64? Normally you would only use base64 to represent binary data or data which contains potentially bad characters for the container in which you intend to store it.  If you really do want to convert it to base64, I can help, but think about this carefully.  Converting data to base64 results in a 4/3 expansion in the size of your data.  The only case in which I can see this being useful is if you need to interface with an existing website or web service which only accepts base64 encoded input.

Comment: ...or do you perhaps mean that you have binary data which you are temporarily representing as Hex strings (perhaps to allow it to exist in Excel cells), which you wish to a) convert back to binary data and b) convert the binary data to base64?

Comment: **Give us a simple example of a typical input string and what you expect as output.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Function Hex2Base64(ByVal sHex)

    Static oNode As Object
    Dim a() As Byte

    If Len(sHex) Mod 2 <> 0 Then
        sHex = Left(sHex, Len(sHex) - 1) & "0" & Right(sHex, 1)
    End If
    If oNode Is Nothing Then
        Set oNode = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument").createElement("Node")
    End If
    With oNode
        .text = ""
        .dataType = "bin.hex"
        .text = sHex
        a = .nodeTypedValue
        .dataType = "bin.base64"
        .nodeTypedValue = a
        Hex2Base64 = .text
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: I have been using http://home.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/ to do my conversions, but needed a way to automate the process.
This code does not seem to provide the same answers as the website converter.

For example, I'm inputting HEX = 00014088F66501013 and getting B64 = AAFAiPZlAQED but only get a #value from your block of code

Comment: @omegastripes Hi how can I make it work for hex to HEX to Base58 ?