# VBScript BrowseForFile() Function - how to specify file types?

Tags: function, csv, vbscript

I found this function on GitHub and it's working great for what I need, but I can't figure out how to specify file type.  It seems to default to "all".

```
Function BrowseForFile()
    With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim tempFolder : Set tempFolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2)
        Dim tempName : tempName = fso.GetTempName() & ".hta"
        Dim path : path = "HKCU\Volatile Environment\MsgResp"
        With tempFolder.CreateTextFile(tempName)
            .Write "<input type=file name=f><script>f.click()" & _
            ";(new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'))" & _
            ".RegWrite('HKCU\\Volatile Environment\\MsgResp', f.value)" & _
            ";close();<" & "/" & "script>"
            .Close
        End With
        .Run tempFolder & "\" & tempName, 1, True
        BrowseForFile = .RegRead(path)
        .RegDelete path
        fso.DeleteFile tempFolder & "\" & tempName
    End With
End Function
```

'Example: msgbox BrowseForFile()

I tried modifying this line:

```
.Write "<input type=file name=f ><script>f.click()" & _
";(new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'))" & _
".RegWrite('HKCU\\Volatile Environment\\MsgResp', f.value)" & _
";close();<" & "/" & "script>"
```

To this:

```
.Write "<input type=file accept=" & chr(34) & "text/plain" & chr(34) & " name=f ><script>f.click()" & _
";(new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'))" & _
".RegWrite('HKCU\\Volatile Environment\\MsgResp', f.value)" & _
";close();<" & "/" & "script>"
```

But, still not working.  Is there any way to use this function and customize the allowed file types?  I want to allow only .csv, .txt, and .log

Comment: Aside: What are you trying to accomplish here? VBScript cannot be used reliably on web pages (and won't work at all on MSIE11+), and Visual Basic as a whole is on its way out.

Comment: I'm aware.  I mainly like how easy it's been to manipulate IE with, but I'm aware I need to let go...  What do you recommend as a replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this function here : [How to add filter to a file chooser in batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369664/how-to-add-filter-to-a-file-chooser-in-batch/38385828#38385828)

```
Function GetFileDlgEx(sIniDir,sFilter,sTitle) 
Set oDlg = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<object id=d classid=clsid:3050f4e1-98b5-11cf-bb82-00aa00bdce0b></object><script>moveTo(0,-9999);eval(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(0).Read("&Len(sIniDir)+Len(sFilter)+Len(sTitle)+41&"));function window.onload(){var p=/[^\0]*/;new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(p.exec(d.object.openfiledlg(iniDir,null,filter,title)));close();}</script><hta:application showintaskbar=no />""") 
oDlg.StdIn.Write "var iniDir='" & sIniDir & "';var filter='" & sFilter & "';var title='" & sTitle & "';" 
GetFileDlgEx = oDlg.StdOut.ReadAll 
End Function
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
sIniDir = CurrentDirectory &"\Myfile.csv" 
sFilter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv|txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|log files (*.log)|*.log|" 
sTitle = "Put a title of your program here :) (-_°)" 
MyFile = GetFileDlgEx(Replace(sIniDir,"\","\\"),sFilter,sTitle) 
wscript.echo MyFile
```

Comment: Holy hell - this function is awesome.  Thank you for this!  Even BETTER than what I had.  Far more customizable.  Cheers!

Comment: So, I'm aware of the traditional .BrowseForFolder method, but since I like the customization possible with this script such as the title bar and how it uses the traditional browse dialogue box, how might I modify this to browse just for a directory?  In other words, leaving every other aspect of this script in tact, simply browsing for a directory instead of a file.  Possible?

Comment: Instead of the `object` tags, I use: `about:<input type=file id=FILE>` so maybe `folder` instead of `file`. The file filter will not be needed.