# How to open file using Open File Dialog

Tags: excel, vbscript, fileopendialog

I've been searching over the web for solution on how to open file using Open File Dialog in VBScript. Can someone point me on the right track?

My code below opens Excel file but I wanted it to be more dynamic in terms that the input file name can be change and not hard coded.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = 0
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
path = objShell.CurrentDirectory
inFileName = "InputFile.xlsx"
inFilePath = path + "\" + inFileName

'Open target workbook
Set objWorkbook1 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(inFilePath, False, True)
MsgBox "Reading Data from " & inFileName & vbNewLine, vbOkOnly + vbInformation, _
       "Reading Data"
```

Comment: have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21565999/3802503) , might help you

Comment: Hi Karthikeyan! Thanks for your response. I was able to used the code in the link you provide but I am looking for a more vb definite one which is native to excel file dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx).

```
Set dialog = objExcel.FileDialog(3)
dialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
dialog.Show

For Each f In dialog.SelectedItems
  Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(f)
  '... do stuff ...
  objWorkbook.Close
Next
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar! That's cool I have intially tested the script and it works as I expected. Thanks for your help.