# How to embed base64 encoder into HTML file using VB Script?

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I have converted an image to base64 encoder now I want to embed this into HTML file using VB Script. How can I do that?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545307/can-a-bmp-file-be-stored-in-an-hta-html-vbscript

Answer (score 0):

You can use UFT's RunScript functionality to do this.

Say you have this file called `addImage.js` (I don't know where you want to insert the `img` I'll assume you can identify the object somehow, this example assumes an `id`).

```
window.addImageToId = function(id, base64) {        
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + base64;
    var parent = document.getElementById(id);
    parent.appendChild(img)
}
```

Then you can do this in the test.

```
'# introduce the function into the document's scope
Browser("B").Page("P").RunScriptFromFile "C:\addImage.js" 
Browser("B").Page("P").RunScript "addImageToId('" & theId & "', '" & theBase64 & "')"
```