# gzip/zip in Classic ASP / VB Script for eBay API

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, zip, ebay-api

I'm using "eBay API > File Transfer > [uploadFile](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/file-transfer/CallRef/uploadFile.html)".

The file I use (I'm hoping to use CSV) needs to be both zipped and base64 encoded.

I have found a script online to encode to base64, but now I need to sort out the zip.

gzip or zip are the formats.

Can anyone suggest a script or library (Classic ASP with VB Script) to allow me to zip my file up ready for upload to eBay..??

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For base64-encoding a string see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506992/1630171). For `gzip` compression you could try [this component](http://www.example-code.com/vbscript/gzip_compressString.asp) (never used it myself, though) or shell out to a `gzip` executable:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "C:\path\to\gzip.exe filename"
```

`gzip` for Windows can be found [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using pkzip25.exe (http://ricardo.ecn.wfu.edu/~cottrell/pkzip.html) for this, called using the same object and method you've got here.