# Base64 Encode a ZIP file using Classic ASP and VB Script

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, zip, base64

I have a zip file, which contains one CSV file.

I need to Base64 encode this zip file to send to eBay (using their API).

I used this website: http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/Base64Encode/ which works nicely, I upload my zip file and it returns a base64 encoded string which eBay likes.

I need to do what this website does, but using Classic ASP and VB Script.

I already have a base64 encode function, from here: http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_base64encode/ so I don't need a script for that. This function takes a parameter, so I need to turn my zip file into a string (I think) to pass into this function.

I have tried using ADODB.Stream and the LoadFromFile method, but the string it returns, after base64 encoding, doesn't match that from the opinionated geek website and isn't accepted by eBay.

This is what I've tried:

```
Dim objStream, strFileText

Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = 1
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile Server.MapPath("myzipfile.zip")

strFileText = Base64Encode(objStream.Read)
Response.Write strFileText

objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing
```

Can anyone help..?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Base64 Encode String in VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496751/base64-encode-string-in-vbscript)

Comment: Thank you ulluoink... I was missing the BinaryToString function... I'll post the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now solved...

I was missing the BinaryToString function between the stream output and the base64 encode.

Now I use:

```
strFileText = Base64Encode(BinaryToString(objStream.Read))
```

Where the new function is...

```
Function BinaryToString(Binary)
  Dim I, S
  For I = 1 To LenB(Binary)
    S = S & Chr(AscB(MidB(Binary, I, 1)))
  Next
  BinaryToString = S
End Function
```

The output from this now matches the output from the opinionated geek tool.

Thanks to ulluoink for pointing me in the right direction!