# Encode Unicode String to Base64 with VBScript

Tags: powershell, unicode, encoding, vbscript

I want to encode a powershell command (a string `(get-date).date`) to base64 in order to run it via `powershell -encodedcommand xxx`.

Using the standard VBS methods (or even https://www.base64encode.org/) I get `KGdldC1kYXRlKS5kYXRl` which does not run.

Using the following powershell script:

```
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```

I get `KABnAGUAdAAtAGQAYQB0AGUAKQAuAGQAYQB0AGUA` which works. The difference appears to be that the command is first encoded as Unicode bytes.

Can anyone provide a VBS Function which does this or the VBS equivalent of Unicode.GetBytes() so that we can get the right string encoded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell only accepts Base64 encodings of **UTF-16 LE-encoded** strings with its
`-EncodedCommand` parameter.
UTF-16 LE is what `Unicode` stands for in [`[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx), and it encodes the vast majority of Unicode characters (code points) as *two* bytes each; it is also the string encoding used *internally* by both VBScript and PowerShell.

By contrast, most VBScript solutions out there use the *single*-byte ASCII encoding, and even the otherwise laudably Unicode-aware https://www.base64encode.org/ only offers *UTF-8*-based encoding (which is a mostly-single-byte-for-Western-languages encoding with other languages' chars. represented as 2-4 bytes).

Here's **a robust UTF-16 LE-based Base64 encoding solution**.

<sup>I've posted a more modular variant that optionally supports *UTF-8* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40118072/45375); the code in both locations builds on [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506992/45375).</sup>

**Example** call:

```vb
Base64EncodeUtf16Le("(get-date).date") ' -> "KABnAGUAdAAtAGQAYQB0AGUAKQAuAGQAYQB0AGUA"
```

**Source** code:<sup>Tip of the hat to [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) for helping to simplify the solution.</sup>

```vb
' Base64-encodes the specified string using UTF-16 LE as the underlying text
' encoding.
Function Base64EncodeUtf16Le(ByVal sText)

    Dim bytesUtf16Le

    ' Create an aux. stream from which we can get a binary (byte array)
    ' representation of the input string in UTF-16 LE encoding. 
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        ' Create a UTF 16-LE encoded text stream...
        .Type = 2  ' adTypeText
        .Charset = "utf-16le"
        .Open
        .WriteText sText
       ' ... and convert it to a binary stream, 
       ' so we can get the string as a byte array
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 1   ' adTypeBinary
        .Position = 2 ' Skip BOM
        bytesUtf16Le = .Read
        .Close
    End With 

    ' Use an aux. XML document with a Base64-encoded element.
    ' Assigning a byte stream (array) to .NodeTypedValue
    ' automatically performs Base64-encoding, whose result can then be accessed
    ' as the element's text.
    With CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument").CreateElement("aux")
        .DataType = "bin.base64"
        .NodeTypedValue = bytesUtf16Le
        Base64EncodeUtf16Le = .Text
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Great!. I was testing but I missed the `utf-16le` option. I've adapted my code to your information, but I have a doubt: Why two `adodb.stream` objects? Is there any case in where the solution with only one could fail? Is there any improvement in using two instances?

Comment: @MCND D'oh! Thanks for that, I've updated my answer - 1 stream is entirely sufficient; a combination of old code and making mistakes while experimenting with a single stream had me wrongly convinced that 2 streams are needed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this will handle all your needs, but at least it matches the output indicated in your question

```vbs
Function ToBase64( ByVal text )
    Const adTypeText = 2
    Const adTypeBinary = 1

    ' Right pad each character with a null
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "(.)"
        .Global = True
        text = .Replace( text, "$1" & Chr(0) )
    End With

    ' Convert String to binary
    With WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = adTypeText
        .CharSet = "us-ascii"
        .Open
        .WriteText text
        .Position = 0
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        text = .Read
    End With

    ' Encode binary as Base64
    With WScript.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0").CreateElement("base64")
        .dataType = "bin.base64"
        .nodeTypedValue = text
        ToBase64 = Replace( .text, vbLf, "" )
    End With
End Function

WScript.Echo ToBase64("(get-date).date")
```

**edited** just to adapt my previous code to the information in [mklement0 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40118450/2861476) where you can find the details of the `powershell` requirements and all the details about how the code works.

```vbs
Function ToBase64( ByVal text )
    Const adTypeText = 2
    Const adTypeBinary = 1

    ' Change string encoding
    With WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        ' Convert input string to UTF-16 LE
        .Type = adTypeText
        .CharSet = "utf-16le"
        .Open
        .WriteText text
        ' Get binary representation of the string
        .Position = 0
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        .Position = 2 ' Skip BOM
        text = .Read
    End With

    ' Encode binary as Base64
    With WScript.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0").CreateElement("base64")
        .dataType = "bin.base64"
        .nodeTypedValue = text
        ToBase64 = Replace( .text, vbLf, "" )
    End With
End Function

WScript.Echo ToBase64("(get-date).date")
```