# How to create fedex label from returned xml data

Tags: xml, soap, asp-classic, fedex

I am able to successfully send a ProcessShipmentRequest thru SOAP and now I am trying to figure out how to create a label with the returned XML for the label section.  We are switchig over from the .net version where the label was automatically created as a pdf and stored on the server.  Below is the label xml.

```
<Barcodes>
<BinaryBarcodes>
<Type>COMMON_2D</Type>
<Value>
Wyk+HjAxHTAyNjI3MDQdODQwHTIwHTc4ODQwMzY3MTk4OTAyMDEdRkRFHTI2NzQ3NDUyNB0zMTMdHTEvMR0xMC4wMExCHU4dNjAwIFMuIFNlY29uZCBTdHJlZXQdU3ByaW5nZmllbGQdSUwdR0RFIFRFU1QgKFBPRCBORUVERUQpHjA2HTEwWkVEMDA3HTExWkpvZSBCbG9nZ3MdMTJaMDE3ODI1NjMzMjIdMTVaMTAzNjY2Nzc4HTIwWhwdMzFaMTAwMTkyMTMyMTQwMDAwNjI3MDQwMDc4ODQwMzY3MTk4OR0zMlowMh0zNFowMR0zOVpBVVNBHR4wOR1GRFgdeh04Hc+H8QQ+g/9AHgQ=
</Value>
</BinaryBarcodes>
<StringBarcodes>
<Type>FEDEX_1D</Type>
<Value>1001921321400006270400788403671989</Value>
</StringBarcodes>
</Barcodes>
</OperationalDetail>
<Label>
<Type>OUTBOUND_LABEL</Type>
<ShippingDocumentDisposition>RETURNED</ShippingDocumentDisposition>
<ImageType>PDF</ImageType>
<Resolution>200</Resolution>
<CopiesToPrint>1</CopiesToPrint>
<Parts>
<DocumentPartSequenceNumber>1</DocumentPartSequenceNumber>
<Image>
JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwovUGFnZXMgMyAwIFIKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL091dGxpbmVzCi9Db3VudCAwCj4+CmVuZG9iagozIDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9UeXBlIC9QYWdlcwovQ291bnQgMQovS2lkcyBbMTggMCBSXQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNCAwIG9iagpbL1BERiAvVGV4dCAvSW1hZ2VCIC9JbWFnZUMgL0ltYWdlSV0KZW5kb2JqCjUgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL0ZvbnQKL1N1YnR5cGUgL1R5cGUxCi9CYXNlRm9udCAvSGVsdmV0aWNhCi9FbmNvZGluZyAvTWFjUm9tYW5FbmNvZGluZwo+PgplbmRvYmoKNiAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvRm9udAovU3VidHlwZSAvVHlwZTEKL0Jhc2VGb250IC9IZWx2ZXRpY2EtQm9sZAovRW5jb2RpbmcgL01hY1JvbWFuRW5jb2RpbmcKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjcgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL0ZvbnQKL1N1YnR5cGUgL1R5cGUxCi9CYXNlRm9udCAvSGVsdmV0aWNhLU9ibGlxdWUKL0VuY29kaW5nIC9NYWNSb21hbkVuY29kaW5nCj4+CmVuZG9iago4IDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9UeXBlIC9Gb250Ci9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQovQmFzZUZvbnQgL0hlbHZldGljYS1Cb2xkT2JsaXF1ZQovRW5jb2RpbmcgL01hY1JvbWFuRW5jb2RpbmcKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjkgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL0ZvbnQKL1N1YnR5cGUgL1R5cGUxCi9CYXNlRm9udCAvQ291cmllcgovRW5jb2RpbmcgL01hY1JvbWFuRW5jb2RpbmcKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjEwIDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9UeXBlIC9Gb250Ci9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQovQmFzZUZvbnQgL0NvdXJpZXItQm9sZAovRW5jb2RpbmcgL01hY1JvbWFuRW5jb2RpbmcKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjExIDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9UeXBlIC9Gb250Ci9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQovQmFzZUZvbnQgL0NvdXJpZXItT2JsaXF1ZQovRW5jb2RpbmcgL01hY1JvbWFuRW5jb2RpbmcKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjEyIDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9UeXBlIC9Gb250Ci9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQovQmFzZUZvbnQgL0NvdXJpZXItQm9sZE9ibGlxdWUKL0VuY29kaW5nIC9NYWNSb21hbkVuY29kaW5nCj4+CmVuZG9iagoxMyAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvRm9udAovU3VidHlwZSAvVHlwZTEKL0Jhc2VGb250IC9UaW1lcy1Sb21hbgovRW5jb2RpbmcgL01hY1JvbWFuRW5jb2RpbmcKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjE0IDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9UeXBlIC9Gb250Ci9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQovQmFzZUZvbnQgL1RpbWVzLUJvbGQKL0VuY29kaW5nIC9NYWNSb21hbkVuY29kaW5nCj4+CmVuZG9iagoxNSAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvRm9udAovU3VidHlwZSAvVHlwZTEKL0Jhc2VGb250IC9UaW1lcy1JdGFsaWMKL0VuY29kaW5nIC9NYWNSb21hbkVuY29kaW5nCj4+CmVuZG9iagoxNiAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvRm9udAovU3VidHlwZSAvVHlwZTEKL0Jhc2VGb250IC9UaW1lcy1Cb2xkSXRhbGljCi9FbmNvZGluZyAvTWFjUm9tYW5FbmNvZGluZwo+PgplbmRvYmoKMTcgMCBvYmogCjw8Ci9DcmVhdGlvbkRhdGUgKEQ6MjAwMykKL1Byb2R1Y2VyIChGZWRFeCBTZXJ2aWNlcykKL1RpdGxlIChGZWRFeCBTaGlwcGluZyBMYWJlbCkNL0NyZWF0b3IgKEZlZEV4IEN1c3RvbWVyIEF1dG9tYXRpb24pDS9BdXRob3IgKENMUyBWZXJzaW9uIDUxMjAxMzUpCj4+CmVuZG9iagoxOCAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvUGFnZQ0vUGFyZW50IDMgMCBSCi9SZXNvdXJjZXMgPDwgL1Byb2NTZXQgNCAwIFIgCiAvRm9udCA8PCAvRjEgNSAwIFIgCi9GMiA2IDAgUiAKL0YzIDcgMCBSIAovRjQgOCAwIFIgCi9GNSA5IDAgUiAKL0Y2IDEwIDAgUiAKL0Y3IDExIDAgUiAKL0Y4IDEyIDAgUiAKL0Y5IDEzIDAgUiAKL0YxMCAxNCAwIFIgCi9GMTEgMTUgMCBSIAovRjEyIDE2IDAgUiAKID4+Ci9YT2JqZWN0IDw8IC9GZWRFeEV4cHJlc3MgMjAgMCBSCi9FeHByZXNzRSAyMSAwIFIKL2JhcmNvZGUwIDIyIDAgUgo+Pgo+PgovTWVkaWFCb3ggWzAgMCA3OTIgNjEyXQovVHJpbUJveFswIDAgNzkyIDYxMl0KL0NvbnRlbnRzIDE5IDAgUgovUm90YXRlIDkwPj4KZW5kb2JqCjE5IDAgb2JqCjw8IC9MZW5ndGggMzg4NwovRmlsdGVyIFsvQVNDSUk4NURlY29kZSAvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGVdIAo+PgpzdHJlYW0KR2F1MEc5b2c3KCZcU1NBSXFUc2svLmY7ZD8wJ2RRN2RaJkZKbj9kZGZLU1hKZmxbY2pOKHByVVpJaU5WOCRdJG0vXmJ0JTVkXD5wNVlxPlgKPEBoMWEsLjYtYD1wX2hlOGB1b0NLMmxlJ0stRTtfTzEsOlQsVi4rXm5GI2YtZSlrODtNZUEhN2wnWDQ8IS9bJFdBPkVdR2FadVVUR2ZWbT4KUUYmRkItNGAoYmA0NG9NMmxGb2lbclV1VWwpdSYzX3MrWVQrOiE5JHMjK28pbCRKQzlFblxvSzhgQE03a0tXTW5xb0BPS21QKyI5PTReNmcKbGYjSiloX3JzSj5BUjJwZDcmXUdNcFwzWUNpSVdMbGEwXW1idUNza2ZrNzE7bF9qXSNxbT42VkxETVx1bkI/IkdGUC0jWkA8WFwqTywqJk0KbWYlMT1JaTdBLVZCZD0/bUkidSo0bCY9RExSXDg+bUola3RaaFNscGc3PiosJGg1RF5dbSxIODRSRVcuKGV1LlhubW90ZmtTP3NkJVBWWlsKKilHMWFrcjpkR2dONiZkWmljIVFSXzFCM28jOCxQaEhnWGhCXWdAdEorTVhvRU1xcFBCaVZXP0FDZTcsWE8uQV5qUVcqKm9fQUNSZWVEJFMKRUIqXjpkSUI/cDB0PWBDSzxaYioybEtRJF1LXCs1U1RGX2htVT1gbGIjYTMkTFxwaC8/SC42SDYuYFREJXNPb2dtODhbSkokXDo0Zz1BL0cKbywvPlkkQ0VXJTBvTGdKZShebyg9YD45QzlLMGsvSEAzSz43OD5zTWhnVScnMlwhKDtEdE42a3IiNDtxTi05R1lhYywnN3JWcUZ0TT04QFwKZV4rbS9EcnVqSlY1dDJqO2YmQGVkajdSQzxSbiRBOGkpTnNYVEpxLlAsVWQpQjI+OGZsKG9zbEwhPkw2MlIrOVlkM2drOGRPUjppL2Fqa0UKNlksQHQrTzsuSUwuYExhcVVkUFNcamxANj9fZExxJUd1LDFnRyp0K1BYSUJLVV1yP3FdQ2MpM082SSIoUShwdFxoS2sxIk5dQV05MVdBMG4KYXVUInAoM0RWWFZKLywvSiwmR2NdTCJhUF46VSI2YFVFOWBOXEAwRWVwRjdxMWBUIjJuRXAvdCg9J3M3M2teVz5gKWhncDA3ZEMxR0M0WWoKKlVfZVBWWXRcam0wQmAja1wxS0BrIVotZiJUYDJPJEd1aG1sdGEjb11fUUpocWBSOGhmTTdMUl07I3AxPi5VIyVIQisnX00/LCUxLjt0Pz4KK2VYNTtDNE9wNCtbNWNhUCVeWDdcYk9FUWcqaD1bJSg/b1Uxa14pTGMhKyE5N0xGM2BaIWIiTE9KP1YmV1wwRiI1cHRRJTNxPT8/MGZFTVoKSSRpVTotbmdxXjVIY3RnMCYhNl8uUl9JYWYyXj1jVDtyZjYjUFJtblMpXlEvXUw1YUZGQ00nPDI/S3Q1LT1QNVInb1dna1xhaTxLQkIoKkgKLjF0OTJqc20uJUc/L3QuPSRXOlltXVspMCUxPGwpaSFqa0lSQkQob21aSlY/KTMkRCxFcDZhJTh1UkBQK1xzRzBtQ1dhJkExVmcrZTk5RWQKZDNmVFo4JEd1aUI9XGBAVFFCcEdDYFpDI1lnPStVIz9fbUZYM0s8KVcjYEZBOCIjZzNkR3V1ajBZLm5eVFgxQ2dxb15JK0pmdG8/JyZuIUwKUSVyNklMRzZtR1kmcEhbO011SnE1XSxQV1lXM00xJi00QjoxWz9NbUhTKSZfMz8rM2UrX1lMaUtFXXJgWnIzWG44JTFhOVwtcDg8WSRgN2MKNjQnInIkQEo9RDJDUWxYJGBxNjQ0S1tUWi4+dFxzJ2ZdV1lGWSZFVVVKNGROWjtPKnBhVHI5VV9kc1FQU1pNPTZUdXI5LkA9YFEnTHBqNmsKaThdInU2YGRlXjpfMCo5RmFQOE9iczgsciEjQUNkXSwyakM2Pjo7MEhkUUxFP10iRmVSW2IuPGBedXBmMm1DNUgjZEclQF01XCUnYlVDMUoKLS5XWW9YKV9CVyRNWSw4QFk/JllAQS5nKC9UYFtROF5uR0w9QzwtYlUxTUxiR1UkWmZbJGhZbz1OQGo7Y2FOJ11OPnU3XlwuXChHKGQwdDIKPjo8LkMrTnArXUozKUlTY1ZCQTdUUUtLMkdSPjNfJiJVbkdfTjlVMU5BWzYwXmo2OFI6KCFwYEpIPTZqalhAQm9wZ0lpMDNtbj9sN09dPDEKciRCb11rYGE7R1VzUl0/TVhDUTErOkJZcFFrbTxWVFNOK2s7SVZlQjAnPEImXSMxLSFsVlRvYTNkYSZeQW0sZk1YaUYoQiJgKDxGJmheQHIKNEZuVyxDdWc2UWVqSlotI14kM1RcP01QYUA9YFA0OGlfV1JgZHBaXykmUV1dMjBHJXU8MGpuRl9yaWJabmRTWzozbTpNSENDPGY8VyxUYXIKX0BsL1hlPiYndG4halQ2Vjw8TDhlakUhPU5dPTxGVSM5Lk5Kb3I/NFNyWyhxIjxWNSpfWy91O19hODNdP0JCaTdua2NpZFllVzoqZENpSlIKXm49OiooLHJJSjNaTCU9LU8ncFVkMiZSQm8rYkA8VSFOMFBsNDEqYEJNTVo7Kj1jPD9LT2I3bDlWSmJyM2BFbEs+bl03VU8iZyonNHVnYV8KSDNOVlIpOC8rOyRwY24iaUUmWlc1V3M0bjQ1L1dPJkRlZUssVU0kRSRdYDYxTjU2Z2lAMy1UUy5fVWEwQWk3JyNKMychXzlKLlMzPXRmUmoKYTgkKERMWD40U247KjJAblg+SU0oMEhAMD89dSw2T0BYV2RLSiZwWG9ZV3FjRyglL0w7IVtIdVRGUTFuXGw1QGg4WVMwWDB0SUdPRSMmUCQKM2tDKkxOU2hYO1YxOk8yM2FbZzInQDU5LEdMcVdHMk42dD4rPiZvTl0mRTk8JUJuZlVMXHBndVxeS0pnVEBybVlAZG1KWmRxZWdUbjJNR0wKX3QhVSVFZ2xmQDo4a042QHJ1ISowcWNTKUg8aVYjIkc8YTArOjU+Umo9ajNrPUtGJ1VYPT1eLWgwX2d1VUlraFw6QVkjL08vOkNNMSVNUicKXkt0N0tKcXA/ZzFjbEVYSW4hUztRVC0hXXF0OWNgMkxXJldIOSQ9OUlONEBZXUItZCdUOjxZYGdudU9ZNVdsPGlYTC1oMGc6UGA4XU1QYDMKTGFTTlJJYEFqSHFKI2VLcVhrcTs1NWsmcVlsL2s9Vm9YUS1SQ1VgZjk+KFwyIzNjYUEjMUZFZ0pqXi1SMkMsO2pBUWljM0xtXTFdOGJbViQKN1tuWEVvU0pNMCUzaGpKOEhwQFU2VV1yMGJGY1FJcSIlOlI3LTluKUFFdWI2QGEqRmRRa2I0Ll49JFVSNkBMOWdINEhySkMqRVdNbWw9OSQKJWc1Ylo2Ozg+Yk5yOTQrLiRcYkZdVF9rRmEvJVQwSScsZmEwRGVQSDYjPis/KFpsWkosX2FfYmdXalU9ZE5qSVhhTD9LRFVPUD89Yz40NU8KZEZDbGFdWTZxP2ppNlVbPSRoa0spRTo5R01uQVI6PjchMEhLPFJtcClcV1lVISw2JmtIbzghOipxaSJJMy89Yis+SydYOyFrJDpCW2hOcUEKLDs2SDhGPSNGQT1aXXVnJFcicD0pUCt1JkpMNllHcSQ3YFxMLkAvQi80aDxmZG5zYXUtOmdFTm4qcVRJQDRSR2opRT0pVCEqYD1AP09qPDUKPE02ZHUrZj4+SlpeMC9sOjAwYlY6UzUlWWUzOyNiYWBgKzpDQUNLYW5rLzVsPF5LTT1iLytkNy8oPz8jMkZAWF9aQSFbMi1zW2dqME5eJDsKJm8rW3NQdSRCXmdRZlU1Vis6YylaSiIjUytWM1ZNQlhVXGU6aWZKc2peVDI0OFdOUjo6MDBkLFBfMi5uTTRqQChPOCElQFkoVzZjZCJlVCIKVzQ2azYmX2o/JFcibG1nUSczYzdvRWNTXmZoLzFcXSY3WDRgNigoWGEjY2FsNjdxNW5SLHRaW25IOldYbWdFRDFDXCxnOSpZWHMpIyZVIigKUHVzTyVqbDM1dT1jLTlJRjFyOSZvP0cjdDNBM0FQLyRcNVdebClHQSdhZGRNUixpbzhYSTRINmM5RHJpbk9IPXFNTi9AOT05a1BDQnFfQWUKN0xTJyhDMDM5RjE8ZDM9JEhhKyMrYFAuLkNFJzU3Kyw0SXJpcFJXYmdWLFBISzxWazFAPiNyWDV0TFVUTCgrM2JeWiRjOkFjVDYrSTNOYk4KJ2cwaCwkSiUrMlgqZzg5LjNMXXRqLz42MVBoKjFiZTNXQyNxOEYjRUsha1FKS3IuL187KzRMbD1NYF9qQGRxT0wvZVZAOiZiIl46WFIzOGkKM0BQQipRayNdKGVKZCQyKGRkJz4+OiwuNENLOmFEXylhXlBcVEMuWyFZTik3ZjxELSdHITpDMy05cWFFPEVaRzNEJDAwUSEvSV8wXDE+QikKWEMsbElCQjxqSyJEZTFzN1M5VyhrJl0/OG5dakNGaXAwSVhSWEM0YFdHSiI3SXE/NUE9PSlJLy8rMTFpPyY+dTwpNnVEYi1QaGFmaGM8SWIKSyFlXDNicyo+VWIoTiR1PS8xRztybUlsNFhpOlZTbURKNmkiYCp1UzpORm1jUHAqZyU9JiRBW1tKX0REcFVsS2BrS2xNYllDTilASEJJZUAKbChDYmBRWGsxUVhET1FcR20/ViwuLV1pTllDUD9jb0NEdTAzZ2RzKGBnPEhSM2lvKig0VkU3ZGl1b29JQXVmPWFuLSsrNU1zI2VzS1xHUVcKJChtais0R3Q1cWpcI2RDK0xIRSdFQjg5cTxPWE5RW15XUktGW2pFPmdbV2dtP3FwN1AqSD05VFtESThaWDs0ZC5RP2k4Y25wZ0BBRj0jTDMKXjMmRCo2OkM/IypaQm5MUTw7bUsuSW46bzsmUjQ1cmckQzBoZyIlSypYUGtVNjZrSzMtLlpLR2BvWnRKJCcwWG46VklSQipCbEwsY1psYyIKRDhOJkw2Pl5aKD9mZEpsMCEnXz8iX28hU01Nb249P05rM006WC8wZ1hHZlpMWDZjbHA5bis+Q0k9O0JzO0A6YTZWMUxHOXJyVCg3Wzdwfj4KZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVuZG9iagoyMCAwIG9iago8PCAvVHlwZSAvWE9iamVjdAovU3VidHlwZSAvSW1hZ2UKL1dpZHRoIDExOAovSGVpZ2h0IDQ5Ci9Db2xvclNwYWNlIC9EZXZpY2VHcmF5Ci9CaXRzUGVyQ29tcG9uZW50IDgKL0xlbmd0aCA0NjEKL0ZpbHRlciBbL0FTQ0lJODVEZWNvZGUgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlXQo+PnN0cmVhbQpHYiIvZUpJXVI/I1huWGtUNkE+WEtuRGJXQiJNWkVhalBwZDRdJyheQFJsdCJrQiJTMCRmJT89bT00Qzs7LiROKGpSY1lSJXNkJmw5JE90XgopJjc9TCg3LWVxcWVALigvU0M5ODQtZkxYZUxaNXFjWjVsQUVCNTU+M0AwPWsiO1JoMmhCY1FMMyZKPzVvW2NIMGJTRk5ePDs7QDQxU1k5bQpjIlpJPVlsI2M0KWBfIllsbU4zJS5BLmxOU2BWZS9ZPCU/LjcoKCkvLmRCWztrIUpbJSclREpcST8rYTc6NW9Oa1lccUVTPjM8STViWm0oSQolZDxAQik4RGJ0M3BLR2NsYlFrMSdpWlZzN05NMFxvJlIqcVU+Z0h1LUZyQ2toPGtIRkcqXCRNPV9zVi8tJFxKRjplLz8+ZlhBK0NDbXBEZQpkU1A2R2N1LFxYJ0FMPWE1SkNbNDZHLmhwMj1VNGVeJGVvXFEjYiptN0M4JC1KQShjWj9ZYCdDOzZKcEhlUGxcJEhFQyF1XipRYSs2Z0VNawpbZkVWKmIuIz5wcj4tV1NmIz5oJlc/dWtrVHNoWWA9L1guNjZBKjtiaXMvZGdAUVhYc3I4bTt+PgplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5kb2JqCjIxIDAgb2JqCjw8IC9UeXBlIC9YT2JqZWN0Ci9TdWJ0eXBlIC9JbWFnZQovV2lkdGggNTQKL0hlaWdodCA1NAovQ29sb3JTcGFjZSAvRGV2aWNlR3JheQovQml0c1BlckNvbXBvbmVudCA4Ci9MZW5ndGggNzcKL0ZpbHRlciBbL0FTQ0lJODVEZWNvZGUgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlXQo+PnN0cmVhbQpHYiIwSmQwVGRxJGo0b0ZeVSwiSFRzOUVJRTswQVQsX0UqTFolb0A3Smw1VjtIJ0NzPVRycURhSC40QmYjYzRPVlQ7KGQjZjxHRTl+PgplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5kb2JqCjIyIDAgb2JqCjw8IC9UeXBlIC9YT2JqZWN0Ci9TdWJ0eXBlIC9JbWFnZQovV2lkdGggMjA5Ci9IZWlnaHQgNzIKL0NvbG9yU3BhY2UgL0RldmljZUdyYXkKL0JpdHNQZXJDb21wb25lbnQgOAovTGVuZ3RoIDE0MDcKL0ZpbHRlciBbL0FTQ0lJODVEZWNvZGUgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlXQo+PnN0cmVhbQpHYiIvYzs2aC0sI1FxWDtWK0pXZlArJmZFam5VOEdgX0wrKmJWQz0iTEA0Tm5xdFxSMTNoTy5jWy9ZUSVdY25OVHJlPUQyPUg+c3MyLiM2SQo0ZyQvTT9HLFExSXJYJl49UWFORjpLQUpValZHLD1PVDJBNzNCSEdnPi4kJDg9NlgxUztuXCc2Y1tobVhYZTVMXUVWaHJiM29gaCIyZiNXcgo0WiJsVUNgIXRzN3VfMzo5VnRrZilKTGElPVxrN0NxXTRgXWMmYDFbTStWTyRQaGk5TT4/PTpAWEghKzFHSyQ2cFEnYyNLU25RcSFhRjBkKwpWL1YpdXFsOy5jSE5eIjAmcVIjSi1KMz47XTx1KT1taXFML0wrTSQpJ0ZZVjY7W1lwUCclcTJuS2JeVSRVPGFGSDRiP1I1QzosM1I+WCw9LAosVFwwQE5XYkdZJzBtW2FdTlRmMEh0U0tXYDMiY29wZl9faSFlOSY+T1NKSV5cSGNaXE1APywhQTVRMWY7NVcsISUxTylRRTdaTjVOQ0FDJwpsXlpXKCQ2IlZjLz0+S3EkVyNoN1plMUBUTDdJT25tb1NPYSMkUGY7WDtfVCVSZURDKyssPHUrM1xdXkEnZkJiOTI8O3JKLWFKPl4oVzIuXwomU1VTRDlgVWUkIzheIzlfSmIuZls+Kzc1OUdmXHQ0O2IoLEJOIz4uJyJSMUpOL1g9ZUJsREhAcE8qR0gpP01QI1RhKSJZK2xycypCRyZscQpWYFBsQ2tHYSdrZ3BqMzJnPVUuciQ4SHIvV2FJajIhMkhlLVBlJkN0Q0VqT0osQUBHTF42N3JTJT5CSypnSC0ySWBTUy1KZyJtYy5PVVppSwpUa3MqJVpwYTtEWyJEUEpfSWMwcEAiOitiTU10L11mUkdkKiU2TmElSSJBNzZDOD0qMCE1JGUuNWApbFBVRyprb2VuaSg1NkZbNVkwRTItLQpIKjlcKUxIR1hLZGgiSClnSlchSG9PUltSLEVvYyUodTsuTDE0I1tmVzxVJjk2RTZUMm0pL1pwSElxTDNuR0lUZ2B0ZGYpRmI8NWdbTmY+OwpvSEIhJFk7UiluX09hJzhtcD1RSmlgdTMoZWllMC5aSksqLj5yLGIpUFNVajtmTUpXRyRBUFZwM19gdGpfUWRdJUMuSFJuYnVMclEmXls3QAorbWBWJEg1ZD1YTmFfaFpyOE08T0l0Si0lS3I1Y2cnUSI9RmN0KF9ITDxLW2ApXSwxL25dLVU7XytAS1g8MD8hWyU+OD0ubmpyTTcpRVNDPgoiTitUbkhUQWhWaWpEckVpdHQ3YSInSDBiQG0qRSYtN2QyQTZQNT04Mk5uSTMtcl5bbmZFZXErJiZjRHM/Mztpc0pFJl1ALzc+VFJKV0U5Zwo3Wm1wMkhiWWBPOm1FbSU7TXNhJTglKDViRENdNSNUY1AiRktfQyhCSjxBImlnYkMpWC0mbS5YUW5RWVZVVlozSk1zWjcwNXVfRjRrSjBEKwpIXz9YYy9tKlFsXk9ZXGNoMyUuR3A+cz1pNmNDZmBXczo6UUoqMEVjWV9AdVkyNUxLLGs4QSlhKV9dXXFjczY7QEhmUkI5OmReZ2ZaUzkhYgo/TGFDX0hQOVdSLl8iaEYtWzNJMUxkZmByTVM0Yzg3XkZKZCtPSGxYVVVuUjVBPXRhVVVJKEU5a05vJ3U+ZkJGbkMrLC9tWmcoJUZMPjtDVAowJUlGbWFdNSRXW1U9cEknS147JlBramA6Nmk7KGosaVAwS0U8JmQxW2pCKHJfTWlHayNGR2E/V1lsVjIlPj5mVEoyLTBmX0d0J1wlN2g6IwpsUSc5LkReNkI+IidITkkzdC1QaWs3PUc3PiE7fj4KZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVuZG9iagp4cmVmCjAgMjMKMDAwMDAwMDAwMCA2NTUzNSBmIAowMDAwMDAwMDA5IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAwNTggMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDEwNCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMTYyIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAyMTQgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDMxMiAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwNDE1IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDA1MjEgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDYzMSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwNzI3IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDA4MjkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDkzNCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAxMDQzIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDExNDQgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMTI0NCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAxMzQ2IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDE0NTIgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMTYyMiAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAyMDAyIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDU5ODEgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwNjYyOCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA2ODg5IDAwMDAwIG4gCnRyYWlsZXIKPDwKL0luZm8gMTcgMCBSCi9TaXplIDIzCi9Sb290IDEgMCBSCj4+CnN0YXJ0eHJlZgo4NDgzCiUlRU9GCg==
</Image>
</Parts>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I BASE64 decoded the data in the *image* tag and it gave me a PDF of a label. So what you probably need to do is BASE64 decode that string and stream the result to the browser or a file (whatever you need).

If you want to stream it to the browser, make sure to add a content-type header in ASP, so the browser knows it must expect a PDF:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
```

An example of how to [BASE64 decode in classic ASP is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496751/base64-encode-string-in-vbscript).

You can also include this snippet I use myself, to save the data as a PDF:

```
Function Base64Data2Stream(sData)
    Set Base64Data2Stream = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
        Base64Data2Stream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        Base64Data2Stream.Open
    With Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0").createElement("b64")
        .dataType = "bin.base64"
        .text = sData
        Base64Data2Stream.Write .nodeTypedValue 'write bytes of decoded base64 to stream
        Base64Data2Stream.Position = 0
    End With
End Function
```

And use it like so:

```
path = "filename.PDF"
set bStream = Base64Data2Stream(pdfdata)
    bStream.SaveToFile path, 2
set bStream = Nothing
```

Make sure you save the file to a path that the IUSR has rights to write to.

Comment: This is great. The pdf it created was an exact match for what is now created in our .net version.