# VBA - MSXML2.XMLHTTP - Pass CREDENTIALS on GITHUB

Tags: excel, vba, github, credentials, msxml

Hope you're all doing well. I've managed to code my way to get to this page:
"https://github.com/decaf-emu/decaf-emu/actions/runs/2458383"

Problem is, I need to be logged-in to be able to see the downloadable artifact *href* (url) on github..

I've tried proposed alternatives such as

```
With xmlhttp
.Open "GET", URL2, False, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD"
.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) Chrome/39.0.2171.71"
.Send

 html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
```

..and many more Frankenstein variations without success.

At this point, I'm really stumped how to get GITHUB to let me extract the download URL of the file.

The end-result should be pasting/msgbox "https://github.com/decaf-emu/decaf-emu/suites/379721547/artifacts/897163"

Can't anyone help me with these credential issues to be able to have access to download it?
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```vb
With xmlhttp
    .Open "GET", URL2, False 'username/password credentials?
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) Chrome/39.0.2171.71"
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization","Basic " & Base64Encode("User:Password")
```

The Base64Encode routine can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496751/)
or there are tools online like https://www.base64encode.net/.

Comment: I tried using the updated version of mklement0 (streamlined version) as well as Patick and it still doesn't work :/ Is there something else maybe that's not right? Because if I search for the id "text-bold" I get the innertext but not the href.. I'm strongly assuming it's because of credential issues based on what I see when I render the page..