# Performance problem in base64 string to XML

Tags: vba, base64, decode

I am using the VBA code below to decode base64 to XML. It works, but only for small size base64 strings. How can I improve it for long strings ?

```
Function f_textBase64Decode(strBase64)
    Dim b
    With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM").createElement("b64")
        .DataType = "bin.base64": .Text = strBase64
        b = .nodeTypedValue
        With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            .Open: .Type = 1: .Write b: .Position = 0: .Type = 2: .Charset = "utf-8"
            f_textBase64Decode = .ReadText
            .Close
        End With
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: "small" and "long" are relative terms: what size are your "long" strings?

Comment: The xml file size is 15MG

Comment: Do you mean `strBase64` is 15MB ?

Comment: Yes. If i save it as xml file it will be 15MG the file contain around 20000 rows

Comment: What is a "MG" ?  That's not a standard unit.

Comment: The  ".ReadText" takes 3-4 minutes for those heavy files. for light xml files it works ok

Comment: Sorry MG = Mega bit

Comment: The strbase64 come from SOAP request

Comment: If you save the encoded text to a file you can try the method from user pizza here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496751/base64-encode-string-in-vbscript/3029969#3029969

Comment: You meam to save the file on my local PC and then to read it?

Comment: At the end i need the xml file to be converted to table in the excel sheet.

Comment: Yes - that way it can be processed line-by-line instead of as one large block

Comment: The Excel conversion seem like a separate question

Comment: OK. Thank you very much